# What is the accurate English translation/meaning of the phrase "In nocte consilium", the motto of Birkbeck College in London?

Tags: phrases, translation, phrase-meaning, latin, proverbs

Not sure if this is the appropriate place to pose this question, but apparently we don't have a Latin Stackexchange...

The motto of [Birkbeck College](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkbeck,_University_of_London) in London is "In nocte consilium". However I have seen widely differing interpretations of this phrase. The Wikipedia page cites a web page from a department of the college (now dead link), stating it means "Study by night". However [a page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(I)) states that this phrase means "Tomorrow is a new day", which I don't see how could be possibly connected to the previous translation. And then on [a page from Wikiproverbs](http://www.wikiproverbs.com/index.php/In_nocte_consilium.), meanings like "An hour in the morning is worth two in the evening." are listed, which seem to be completely contrary to the first translation.

Finally, on the page http://distichalatina.blogspot.com/2012/01/in-nocte-consilium.html, a whole passage is displayed, stating:

> In Nocte Consilium
>
> Consilium in tenebris capias et nocte profunda:
>
> Humanis obstat sensibus alma dies.

--

> Before thou bring thy Workes to Light,
>
> Consider on them, in the Night.

Which I find most plausible.

How shall this phrase be interpreted in English exactly? Surely a college that adopts this motto should have a clear idea about what it means before doing so? However, Googling doesn't reveal any official information on it given by the college...

Comment: I think most people would say *Tomorrow is a new day* is the best (or at least, most *common*) equivalent. The original Latin probably had more the sense of [*Night is the mother of counsel*](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=YrVpVovOKoiPoAeFpoGIBg&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22In+nocte+consilium%22+%22Night+is+the+mother+of+counsel%22) (i.e. - don't make momentous decisions hastily, sleep on it first). You'd expect a place of learning to endorse the idea that people should be careful and considered in their decision-making.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think "Tomorrow is a new day" really doesn't have the same meaning as "study at day and then, at night, think over what you've learned" though?

Comment: I've no idea why that establishment chose that particular motto, but apparently it's not that old (it was established as the ["London Mechanics' Institute"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkbeck,_University_of_London#Founding) in 1823). Older universities weren't very "forward-looking" (medieval society *hated* the idea of change), but Birkbeck was obviously a man much interested in scientific/cultural *advance*. I seriously doubt the choice of motto had anything to do with the idea of a "weighted circadian rhythm" in respect of the learning process for students there.

Comment: Why don't you ask the college?

Comment: ...though it may be worth noting that one of their "rivals", the Oxford-based  Bodleian Library, [had no artificial light until a century after Birbeck was "founded"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22In+nocte+consilium+as+its+motto%22). But since Birbeck didn't have a "stable home" for many decades, I doubt they were crowing about the fact that their reading rooms had gaslight.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The opening words on Birkbeck's web-site say it all: *Birkbeck is London's only specialist provider of evening university study, offering part-time and full-time courses by evening study at all levels*. (It so happens that my son is a PhD student there - though, in his case, a *mature* full-timer). It seems almost certain to me that the motto has something to do with the evening-study specialisation.

Comment: @WS2: Yeah - I have to admit I was really just gobbing off with my first couple of comments. By the time I'd looked a bit more and posted my *third* comment I was coming round to the idea that it might have been deliberately chosen for that more "literal" allusion, even though it was probably never a significant element in the original Latin context. But there are really two separate issues here - why did Birbeck choose it, and what does it mean in more general contexts (to the extent that it still occurs today in other contexts).

Comment: @WS2: I think that must be right. When I was guest speaker in a Birkbeck applied linguistics seminar back in 2002 it was an evening class. I didn't think anything of it at the time, but it makes sense of the motto, and it makes sense that a school started to train mechanics would have evening classes for workingmen. Not something I knew before; thanks.

Comment: @JohnLawler  They do have day-time students. But I think Birkbeck also has a high proportion of *mature* post-graduate students. I am not sure if you use that term in the US. But it means someone who has taken a break from education and gone back to it. *Mature*, as an expression to describe students, seems to me to be going out of fashion, perhaps because it is thought to be ageist.

Comment: I've walked past Birkbeck College many times, and the crescent moon in place of the dot over the 'i' on its signs might be a clue.  And apart from variations in how 'consilium' might be translated, 'in nocte' must surely be 'in the night' or 'by night', so translations such as 'Tomorrow is a new day' are simply whimsical.

Comment: I can never walk in Malet Street without sensing shivers up my spine. Senate House was used in the film of Orwell's 1984 - I believe as *the Ministry of Love* with its infamous room number 101.

Comment: Thanks for the tipoff, @WS2.  I'll look out for that next time.

Answer (score 1):

> *In Nocte Consilium*
>   Counsel in the night (Judgment at night)
>
> *Consilium in tenebris capias et nocte profunda:*
>   You should<sup>*</sup> take counsel (Consider your judgment) in the darkness and in the deep night (late at night)
>
> *Humanis obstat sensibus alma dies.*
>   The nurturing day is a hindrance to human perception (understanding).

English has the idiom "Sleep on it," meaning withhold immediate judgment, but it lacks the notion of active consideration at night.

<sub>*The verb of the main clause is second person, present tense, subjuctive mood, active voice -- the so-called *jussive* subjunctive.  It expresses an exhortation or command.</sub>

Comment: Note also the emblem of the college, with its lamps/candles (for presumably burning the midnight oil !) and the owl, symbol of wisdom since the time of Minerva's worship as goddess.

[A porch way of the college on Malet Street shows][1] "Aladdin"-type lamps, rather than candles, in relief with the owl.

[1]:https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@51.5220476,-0.1309286,3a,40.3y,55.07h,91.22t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s8WLRZkwP8HJRIFgOTgdBSA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1